# How to search and display records from a table in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to create a search form for the users so that they can search for one field and get the all records matching that.

I have a books model that has fields:
`name:string, author_id:integer, publisher_id:integer, category_id:integer, status:string`.

I have created a new controller that has a search field for the book name.

Now, when I type in the Book Name in that search field I want to display all the book records matching that name in the page as a normal rails table.

How do I get this to be done? Really confused.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller(assumed the user's searched string is in params[:name])

```
 @books = Book.where("name like ?", "%#{params[:name]}%")
```

And then you can loop over this `@books` and show them in table

**EDITED after comment**

This variable @books contains all the instances of books. You need to loop over this variable in your view file (haml or erb). By loop over I meant use each method.

Comment: where do I look over @books?